# Java common method/function for duplicate code

Tags: java, testing, automated-tests, testng, listener

I have a duplicate code in my Java TestNg listener method `onFinish()` and want to separate that out in a function so that I can just call it twice. Here is my method below:

```
@Override
    public void onFinish(ITestContext testContext) {
    HashMap<Object, Object> map = new HashMap<Object,Object>();
        Object key_id = new Object();
        map.put(key_id, "id");
        Object key_result = new Object();
        map.put(key_result, "result");

        //Check for all the FAILED tests
        for (ITestResult failedTest : testContext.getFailedTests().getAllResults()) {
            Method method = failedTest.getMethod().getConstructorOrMethod().getMethod();
            TestInfo annotation = method.getAnnotation(TestInfo.class);
            try {
                if(annotation!=null) {
                    for(String test_id: annotation.id()) {
                        map.put(map.get(key_result), Status.AUTOFAIL.getValue());
                        Integration.addTestResult(map);
                    }
              } catch (SecurityException | IOException
                    | TestRailApiException | NullPointerException e) {
                TestLogger.logError("Failed to find the annotation");
            }
        }

    //Check for all the SKIPPED tests
        for (ITestResult skippedTest : testContext.getSkippedTests().getAllResults()) {
            Method method = skippedTest.getMethod().getConstructorOrMethod().getMethod();
            TestInfo annotation = method.getAnnotation(TestInfo.class);
            try {
                if(annotation!=null) {
                    for(String test_id: annotation.id()) {
                        map.put(map.get(key_result), Status.AUTOSKIP.getValue());
                        Integration.addTestResult(map);
                    }
              } catch (SecurityException | IOException
                    | TestRailApiException | NullPointerException e) {
                TestLogger.logError("Failed to find the annotation");
            }
        }
```

As can be seen from the method above that the only difference between two ***for*** loops is I check for failed tests first, and then skipped tests in another loop. Internal difference is I push AUTOFAIL as a status of tests first and then AUTOSKIP for all skipped tests.

As a good practice, I want to separate this out in common function and just call that function to send `AUTOFAIL` and `AUTOSKIP`.

Comment: That's a good idea. What have you tried ?

Comment: I created two separate functions for failed and skipped tests respectively but then I need a common function. Also the 'map.put(map.get(key_result), Status.`AUTOSKIP`.getValue());'  and ...`AUTOFAIL` needs to have something in common which is not allowing me to make that as a separate function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extract the loop into a separate method and parametrize it with what you're looping over:

```
void loop(Collection<ITestResult> results, Status status){
    for(ITestResult result : results){
        (... use status here ...)
    }
}
```

and call it with: `loop(testContext.getFailedTests().getAllResults(), Status.AUTOFAIL)` and `loop(testContext.getSkippedTests().getAllResults(), Status.AUTOSKIP)`

Of course, that's not all the improvements you can make here, but this solves your original question, I believe.